# Has anyone interfaced ROS with an Allen Bradley Compact Logix or Control Logix plc?

Tags: control, ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking to interface ROS with an Allen Bradley PLC and I was curious if anyone has ever set up communications like this before?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197146/has-anyone-interfaced-ros-with-an-allen-bradley-compact-logix-or-control-logix-plc?/) by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-11-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have used the [Epics library](http://www.aps.anl.gov/epics/) for communicating with AB PLCs.  It's not a ROS interface exactly, but it can easily allow a ROS node (or any C++ program) to communicate with the PLC.  The libraries typically communicate at a *tag* level with the PLC (similar to most other methods).

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any drivers / bridges available for integration AB PLCs with ROS.

As these devices are most often used in industrial contexts, you might want to try the ROS-Industrial [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev). It might be that something does exist, but hasn't been announced.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Clearpath has a node which we've used for interfacing with a AB PLCs via Ethernet/IP - I believe the models in question are ControlLogix. However, for a few reasons, they can't be open-sourced - please get in touch if you'd like to license them (email in profile).

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1